# Python CLI Interface subpages

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-interface

Hi so I'm a python beginner, and I wanted ask a question. Is there any way to make subpages in python CLI (something like subpages in GUI)? Is it even possible? So what i wanted to do is that the first thing the program shows is to ask whether the person whom runs the code is an admin or a user, and it will lead the person somewhere corresponding to the answer from the first question asked. Originally, when we run a code in a CLI, lets say in MAC terminal, the past code is not deleted. But I wanted all of it to be deleted so it looks like a subpage. It's not really a subpage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.